# Restrict some url pattern in a apache redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I am writing a redirect to match any url of the patter /message/* here.

```
RewriteRule ^/message/(.+)$ http://abet.in/message/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

**Now I want to modify it by not allowing some string pattern in url.**

```
RewriteCond to check /message/index.html in the url. 

1. Check if the request url contains /message/index.html.
2. If the condition is not met then do a redirect.
```

I tried the following methods. But I am not sure whether they are correct or not.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/message/index

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/message/index [NC]
```

Could some one tell how to do this.

Comment: Have you had a look here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond ?

Comment: @Jon. I tried it. I also have update the question but not sure if they are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%{THE_REQUEST}` contains a string that looks like this for a regular page request:

```
GET /message/index.html HTTP/1.1
```

And `%{REQUEST_URI}` looks like this:

```
/message/index.html
```

So your 2nd option is almost correct. You don't need a `/` at the start of the *Pattern* for RewriteRules.

Additionally, these two rules will prevent all requests that start `/message/index` from being redirected):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/message/index [NC]
RewriteRule ^message/(.+)$ http://abet.in/message/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

If you only want to prevent `/message/index.html` and not `/message/index.php` or `/message/index-of-something-else` then do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/message/index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^message/(.+)$ http://abet.in/message/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```