# Rewrite condition to particular URL and redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a redirect rule that redirects a url of pattern `/abcd/* to http://myweb.com/abcd/*`.

I want to apply this redirect except /abcd/index.html.

I have tried this.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/abcd/index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abcd/index [NC]
RewriteRule ^/abcd/(.+)$ http://myweb.com/abcd/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

I am not sure if it  is correct.

Please suggest me the correct way of doing this.

Comment: This looks fine. If you get no effect when adding your exception rules, then probably you did not restart the http server process?

Comment: @arkascha. Can you confirm if RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/abcd/index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abcd/index [NC] are correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict some url pattern in a apache redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183595/restrict-some-url-pattern-in-a-apache-redirect)

Comment: @Patan: Your code is not correct actually. If you are matching URI=`/sms/anything` then URI obviously cannot start with `/abcd/index.html` hence `RewriteCond` is not even needed. If you explain your question clearly then probably we can help you better.

Comment: @anubhava. Sorry for the wrong input. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule without leading slash in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abcd/index [NC]
RewriteRule ^abcd/(.+)$ http://myweb.com/abcd/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

- Difference is `^abcd/(.+)$` instead of ^/abcd/(.+)$
- Your 2 conditions were redundant so I reduced it to one.
- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.